# Slick Slider - Display counter on multiple sliders

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I have multiple slick sliders on my front-page. Now I want to add a counter which shows the current slid and the max slide.

So for example slider with id `33` has 4 images so it should show `1 of 4` and when going to next slide it should show `2 of 4`. It is already working but all the other slides on the front-page also go 1 up when I slide on a slider. It should only happen on the slider I did change.

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
$('.image-slider').each(function (key, item){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");

    var sliderId = '#' + id;
    var appendArrowsClassName = '#' + id + 'slider__arrows';

    var $status = $('.slider-paging');

    $(sliderId).on('init reInit afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
        //currentSlide is undefined on init -- set it to 0 in this case (currentSlide is 0 based)
        var i = (currentSlide ? currentSlide : 0) + 1;
        $status.text(i + '/' + slick.slideCount);
    });

    $(sliderId).slick({
        infinite: true,
        dots: false,
        appendArrows: (appendArrowsClassName),
        prevArrow: '<div class="left d-inline-block"><i class="fas fa-caret-circle-left"></i></div>',
        nextArrow: '<div class="left d-inline-block"><i class="fas fa-caret-circle-right"></i></div>'
    });
});
```

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

-JS

```
var cnt = 1;
$(".slider").each(function () {
    $(this).attr('id', function (index) {
        return "sld-" + cnt;
    });
    cnt++;
});

$('.slider').each(function(key, item){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var sliderId = '#' + id;

    if ($(sliderId).length) {
        
        var currentSlide;
        var slidesCount;
        var sliderCounter = document.createElement('div');
        sliderCounter.classList.add('slider-counter');

        var updateSliderCounter = function(slick, currentIndex) {
        currentSlide = slick.slickCurrentSlide() + 1;
        slidesCount = slick.slideCount;
        $(sliderCounter).text(currentSlide + '/' +slidesCount)
        };

        $(sliderId).on('init', function(event, slick) {
            $(sliderId).append(sliderCounter);
        updateSliderCounter(slick);
        });

        $(sliderId).on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide) {
        updateSliderCounter(slick, currentSlide);
        });

        $(sliderId).slick({
            slidesToShow: 1,
            dots: false,
            adaptiveHeight: true,
        });
    }
});
```

-html

```
<div class="slider">
  <img>
  <img>
  <img>
</div>
```

-CSS

```
.slider-counter {
                    position: absolute;
                    font-size: 20px;
                    letter-spacing: 2px;
                    font-weight: 400;
                    top: 5px;
                    left: 45px;
                    z-index: 11;
                    pointer-events: none;
                }
```